# Zoom in and out without the need to hold down crtl or alt key

Tags: zoom

Zoom in and out without the need to hold down **crtl** or **alt** key would make navigation much easier and faster.
It is really a question why **developers/UI/UX designers** of many of design softwares do not pay attention to this important fact that the user might do zoom in and out hundreds of times in a day and forcing him/her to hold down the **ctrl** or **alt** key all the time is tiresome and less productive.
Hope they understand this important fact and do accordingly to solve the problem like what **Inkscape** and **Gimp** have done to make it possible to choose the preferred settings.

**Question**
Is there a way one could achieve this in **adobe xd** or in **figma**? Tried **AutoHotKey** software to convert **mouse scroll** to **ctrl down + mouse scroll** but it skips some steps and moves the screen up and down between some steps.
Is there any **plugin** or any different approach to make it possible to **zoom** in and out without the need to keep **ctrl** or any other modifer key down?

*Appreciate your share of knowledge.*

Comment: Adobe has its own switch in prefs, figma I've never used. The advantage of alt or ctrl is that you can, for instance, reserve alt/scroll for Adobe & Ctrl/scroll for the system, leaving just scroll to do actuall scrolling.

Comment: @John - OP doesn't want scroll, OP wants zoom. i suppose you could set up a multi-button mouse with the required modifier for zoom, even on a per-app basis [I do that heavily, for many features across many apps] but on a standard 2-button +wheel, maybe not.

Comment: Thank you for the correction of my idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any 3rd party plug ins for this and you're right, we do zoom in and out hundreds of times a day.

One tip I use a lot: In the left panel, where you have your pages, frames, sections, etc.: Double-click the icon for the frame, image, section, etc., that you want to go to. It auto-zooms you to that object. Saves a lot of time. Hope that helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).